# How to use &nbsp; inside of div > script

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I want to use &nbsp inside of my script :

```
              <div class="badge-danger" id="current_date">
                <script>
                  function CurrentDate() {
                    let current = new Date();
                    let cDate = current.getDate() + ' - ' + (current.getMonth() + 1) + ' - ' + current.getFullYear();
                    let cTime = current.getHours() + ":" + current.getMinutes() + ":" + current.getSeconds();
                    let dateTime = cDate + ' ' + cTime;
                    document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = dateTime;
                  }
                  setInterval(CurrentDate, 1000);
                </script>
            </div>
```

I don't know where to do it inside of this div I'm used to do it like this :

```
                <span style="font-weight: bold">&nbsp;Flash&nbsp;News</span>
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: I don't see any `&nbsp` in your JS

Comment: Why do you need it at all?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Yes this is my question how can I add it ?

Comment: @j08691 cause I want to have the date in a single row; Once I visit my website on my phone It's getting divided like this  : 
21 - 8 - ("\n")
2022 ("\n")
21:20:14

Comment: Try using CSS instead. `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @j08691 the \n just to let u know the space ofc I don't visualize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using a css : white-space: nowrap;:

My code :

```
              <div class="badge-danger" id="current_date" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <script>
                  function CurrentDate() {
                    let current = new Date();
                    let cDate = current.getDate() + ' - ' + (current.getMonth() + 1) + ' - ' + current.getFullYear();
                    let cTime = current.getHours() + ":" + current.getMinutes() + ":" + current.getSeconds();
                    let dateTime = cDate + '<br>' + cTime;
                    document.getElementById("current_date").innerHTML = dateTime;
                  }
                  setInterval(CurrentDate, 1000);
                </script>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html code in your string as it goes to `innerHTML` anyway. So for example `let dateTime = cDate + '&nbsp;' + cTime;` works